# Magento2.3.0 Getting error, when Import Group product via CSV

Tags: error, import, csv, grouped-products, magento2.3.0

I am using magento2.3.0 when I import CSV through group product with associate product getting an error in back end side. If anyone has an idea please share your inputs.

```
{"error": "Invalid file upload attempt: You cannot define a correlation name 'oi' more than once"}
```

Comment: Please check with your csv, something wrong in file.

Comment: I know this Please check with your csv, something wrong in file

Comment: I want result in your side

Comment: i'm tested in my side, its working fine. please check with your csv.

Comment: i am using commerce extension with group product for product import/export

Comment: please go thorough other q "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281299/magento2-how-to-pass-argument-parameters-with-multiple-class/281317#281317"